# 2D game tiled collision detection

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, xna-4.0

I've got something like this:

```
        // checking on which tile are players corners
        // ignore this big mess below, please. It can be put in smaller
        //  equations, but for now it does its job
        left_downX = ((int)Position.X) / 32 * 32 / 32 - map.mapOffsetX / 32 * 32 / 32;
        left_downY = ((int)Position.Y + height) / 32 * 32 / 32 - map.mapOffsetY / 32 * 32 / 32;

        right_downX = ((int)Position.X + width) / 32 * 32 / 32 - map.mapOffsetX / 32 * 32 / 32;
        right_downY = ((int)Position.Y + height) / 32 * 32 / 32 - map.mapOffsetY / 32 * 32 / 32;

        left_upX = ((int)Position.X) / 32 * 32 / 32 - map.mapOffsetX / 32 * 32 / 32;
        left_upY = ((int)Position.Y) / 32 * 32 / 32 - map.mapOffsetY / 32 * 32 / 32;

        right_upX = ((int)Position.X + width) / 32 * 32 / 32 - map.mapOffsetX / 32 * 32 / 32;
        right_upY = ((int)Position.Y) / 32 * 32 / 32 - map.mapOffsetY / 32 * 32 / 32;

        // checking if there is collision and responding to it
        if (map.mapData[left_downX, left_downY] == (int)Map.Tiles.air &&
            map.mapData[left_upX, left_upY] == (int)Map.Tiles.air)
        {
            if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                Speed.X = playerSpeed;
                Direction.X = MOVE_LEFT;
            }
        }
        if (map.mapData[right_downX, right_downY] == (int)Map.Tiles.air &&
            map.mapData[right_upX, right_upY] == (int)Map.Tiles.air)
        {
            if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {
                Speed.X = playerSpeed;
                Direction.X = MOVE_RIGHT;
            }
        }
        if (map.mapData[left_downX, left_downY] == (int)Map.Tiles.air &&
            map.mapData[right_downX, right_downY] == (int)Map.Tiles.air)
        {
            if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            {
                Speed.Y = playerSpeed;
                Direction.Y = MOVE_DOWN;
            }
        }
        if (map.mapData[left_downX, left_downY] == (int)Map.Tiles.air &&
            map.mapData[right_downX, right_downY] == (int)Map.Tiles.air)
        {
            if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            {
                Speed.Y = playerSpeed;
                Direction.Y = MOVE_UP;
            }
        }
```

And as it seems to work correctly, it doesn't.
For example, when player collides with ground, it stays in it and can't move to any directions.
It's similar when colliding only with tiles on sides, but there, you can move to the different side.

What did I wrong?
Maybe there are better ways for checkng collisions without looping throught all tiles?

Answer (score 1):

The first 8 lines of your code should be replaced with a Rectangle object, which should be the same size/location as your Sprite.

Then you can just call the [Rectangle.Intersects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersects.aspx) method against the tiles you are checking against collision.

Comment: but it checks collisions well and I also don't want to loop throught all of the tiles. I've got problem with responces, as player gets stuck just standing stick, or floats throught walls in some cases, sometimes just slides.

Comment: Best thing to do with a Tile based map, is to only check the Tiles that are near the object being checked for Collision.  This should be easy enough to do with the coordinates of the object in question.  To me, your player gets stuck because your collision is not working properly.